# Dagger 2 Unable to install module via contributesAndroidInjector for fragment

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to figure out why I am unable to install a module into my fragment subcomponent via `@ContributesAndroidInjector`. For instance:

**The following works (compiles and is properly injected),**

```
@Module(includes = ColumnWidthModule.class)  
public abstract class GalleryFragmentModule
{
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract GalleryFragment bindGalleryFragment();
}
```

**but the following does not compile:**

```
@Module  
public abstract class GalleryFragmentModule
{
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = ColumnWidthModule.class)
    abstract GalleryFragment bindGalleryFragment();
}
```

**The compiler error I'm getting is this:**

```
AppComponent.java:24: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @javax.inject.Named("columnWidth") java.lang.Integer cannot be provided 
without an @Provides-annotated method.

UPDATE: Here is the full error:

error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @javax.inject.Named("columnWidth") java.lang.Integer cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public interface AppComponent
   ^
A binding with matching key exists in component: GalleryFragmentModule_BindGalleryFragment.GalleryFragmentSubcomponent
  @javax.inject.Named("columnWidth") java.lang.Integer is injected at
      GalleryFragment.columnWidth
  javax.inject.Provider<GalleryFragment> is injected at
      GalleryActivity.galleryFragmentProvider GalleryActivity is injected at
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [AppComponent → ActivityBindingModule_BindGalleryActivity.GalleryActivitySubcomponent]
  It is also requested at: GalleryFragment.AutoFitGridLayoutManager(…, columnWidth)
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
  dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [AppComponent → ActivityBindingModule_BindGalleryActivity.GalleryActivitySubcomponent → GalleryFragmentModule_BindGalleryFragment.GalleryFragmentSubcomponent]
1 error
```

**The module itself looks like this:**

```
@Module
public class ColumnWidthModule
{
    @Provides
    @Named("columnWidth")
    static int columnWidth()
    {
        return 300;
    }
}
```

**and here is where I inject the variable:**

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Inject
    @Named("columnWidth")
    int columnWidth;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this); 
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    // rest of code not shown 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you'd inject `columnWidth` in your activity (or something else higher scoped) as well, but you didn't include the full error printed _after_ `..cannot be provided..`, so it's hard to say

Comment: @Vinnie Can you try some other dependency (like a random class SomeObject) without @Named? If that works, this seems like an issue

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Is there a reason why I would need to inject columnWidth in my activity/higher scope when it's only needed by the fragment?

Comment: @Vairavan It doesn't work with a random class either. Seems like an issue with `@ContributesAndroidInjector` for fragments?

Comment: @Vinnie I didn't say you should inject it there, I said it seems something there _requires_ it. Either you also inject it in your activity, or one of the classes that needs it is `@ActivityScope` If you include the full error it would be listed there

Comment: For me, It worked as long as i didn't use @Named or custom qualifiers.

Comment: @Vairavan we should be able to provide named and qualifiers though right?

Comment: Yes and that whats i meant by an issue. you could raise a bug once you have a setup that works without @Named

Comment: @Vairavan As requested, I've updated the question with the full error. The columnWidth is only intended to be used/injected in the GalleryFragment.

Comment: I've resolved the issue. It was because my activity uses a `Provider<GalleryFragment>`, and so that made the activity also dependent on columnWidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to fix this one of two ways:**

---

1. I noticed that my activity injects a provider for my fragment, like so:

   ```
   public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HasSupportFragmentInjector
   {
       @Inject
       DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> fragmentInjector;

       @Inject
       Provider<GalleryFragment> galleryFragmentProvider;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           AndroidInjection.inject(this);
           // ...

           getSupportFragmentManager()
               .beginTransaction()        
               .add(R.id.fragment_container, galleryFragmentProvider.get(), null)
               .commit();

       }
   }
   ```

   The `GalleryActivity` has a `Provider<GalleryFragment>`, which means that it is also dependent on `columnWidth`. In other words, `columnWidth` is a dependency of `GalleryFragment`, and `GalleryFragment` in turn is a dependency of `GalleryActivity`. Removing the `galleryFragmentProvider` and changing the fragment transaction to just use a `new GalleryFragment()` will fix this:

   ```
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .add(R.id.fragment_container, new GalleryFragment(), null).commit();
   ```

---

2. Another way to fix this and continue using the `Provider<GalleryFragment>` in the activity is to install the `ColumnWidthModule` to the activity's `contributesAndroidInjector` instead, namely this:

   ```
   public abstract class ActivityBindingModule
   {
       @ActivityScope
       @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = { 
           GalleryFragmentModule.class, 
           ColumnWidthModule.class })
       abstract GalleryActivity bindGalleryActivity();
   }
   ```

   I guess the reason why it worked is because it's pretty much equivalent to what I posted above:

   ```
   @Module(includes = ColumnWidthModule.class)  
   public abstract class GalleryFragmentModule
   {
       @ContributesAndroidInjector
       abstract GalleryFragment bindGalleryFragment();
   }
   ```